# Por que Inteligência Artificial e Aprendizagem de Máquina são matérias diferentes?

Tags: inteligência-artificial, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Ao procurar cursos especializados de programação ou com demanda de mercado, dois deles se destacam:

- IA - Inteligência Artificial (ou AI - Artificial Intelligence)
- AM - Aprendizado de Máquina (ou ML - Machine Learning).

Ao meu ver, ML poderia ser uma subcategoria de AI. Então por qual motivo ele é um curso totalmente distinto? Teria a ver pelo motivo de serem assuntos muito complexos ou fazerem mais ou menos uso de algorítimos matemáticos?

Comment: Uma máquina que aprende não seria inteligente? E a inteligência de uma máquina, não seria artificial?

Comment: Não tenho grande conhecimento nesses aspectos, mas vejo que IA é uma disciplina muito abrangente, que a AM está dentro dessa disciplina, o AM é mais centralizado em teorias de como uma máquina aprende e os padrões que ela pode reconhecer.

Comment: Vixi, colega... acho que essa pergunta tende a ser baseada em opiniões, hein? *Na minha opinião* você tem razão, no sentido de que os assuntos são relacionados (e de que AM é, de certa forma, uma disciplina da IA). Mas pode haver quem discorde, talvez porque enxergue o conhecimento aplicado da AM mais como tendo origem na estatística, por exemplo. Já a escolha por ter um curso separado pode decorrer meramente da quantidade de assunto a ser tratado (já que ambas as áreas são *enormes*). Enfim, eu me pergunto sobre o quão construtiva vai ser essa discussão em particular. :/

Comment: @LuizVieira concordo que opiniões devem ser evitadas e respeitadas, entretanto nesse caso as evidências dos termos apontam para uma direção específica...https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Machine_Learning_Research Não envio este link por ser wiki, mais pela editora...

Comment: @LuizVieira espero ansiosamente uma das suas magnificas respostas sobre o assunto haha

Comment: haha Obrigado pela consideração, @MarceloBonifazio. Mas as respostas já foram dadas (incluindo em comentários) pelos demais colegas. E a pergunta acabou de ser fechada (automaticamente, aliás). Eu gosto do assunto, mas acho o fechamento justo porque essa discussão é difícil (e bastante opinativa, na minha opinião rs). Por que Matemática e Estatística são matérias diferentes? Por que se estuda Lógica na Engenharia, na Computação e na Filosofia? Veja como essas perguntas são muito similares. Enfim, mesmo se não fosse opinativo, dificilmente acho que seria construtivo para este site.

Comment: Curiosamente, hoje o UOL publicou [um artigo sobre cientistas usando dados para prever de tudo](https://noticias.uol.com.br/ciencia/ultimas-noticias/redacao/2017/01/16/big-data-e-colaboracao-permite-prever-de-epidemias-a-ataques-terroristas.htm). Esse tipo de processo (em que dados são usados para se construir um modelo preditivo) certamente é parte importante da AM. Note como embora o artigo não cite uma única vez a IA, cita "modelos matemáticos", "modelo estatístico", e "[...] matemática e estatística são os ingredientes da receita do bolo perfeito".

Comment: Todas as respostas só me fizeram pensar que um curso vendido apenas como sendo de IA está errado. Deve se especificar quais tópicos da IA este curso aborda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um adendo, talvez essa imagem seja mais explicativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte da imagem: https://www.razorrobotics.com/artificial-intelligence

Machine Learning pode sim ser considerado um sub-item de Inteligencia Artificial, as duas matérias são intrinsecamente ligadas, muitos conceitos que aprende em IA são depois empregados com ML.
Podemos ainda fazer uma analogia com Calculo Diferencial e Integral, ou Matemática Discreta por exemplo que são sub-itens de Matemática, porém existem muitos conceitos diferentes do que se aprende em um módulo de Matemática puro.

As matérias são ensinadas em módulos diferentes porque existem muitas aplicações e conceitos distintos.

Lembro que na faculdade aprendi esse conceito, do qual acredito até certo ponto:

Inteligencia Artificial pode ser considerado qualquer sistema não humano que realiza determinada tarefa autônoma, sem necessidade de intervenção de uma inteligencia biológica. **Qualquer algoritmo que sirva pra alguma finalidade pode ser considerado uma inteligencia artificial**;

- Por exemplo um sistema que receba X idades e calcule a mediana dessas idades é um tipo de IA. Não há intervenção humana para o cálculo da idade, a não ser em imputar as idades para a máquina fazer o calculo automaticamente, a isso se dá o nome de IA Fraca.

Aprendizado de Máquina funciona como um sistema que aprende qual comportamento deve seguir dependendo das iterações que o mesmo tiver. De inicio possui um comportamento padrão, mas que com o tempo, dependendo do que entrar e da saída esperada, pode ou não mudar esse comportamento.

- [Um exemplo](http://caza.la/synaptic/#/xor) utilizando essa magnifica biblioteca em js: [synaptic.js](http://caza.la/synaptic/#/), especializada em redes neurais. Neste exemplo é utilizado um algoritmo perceptron [que é uma sub-categoria de redes neurais, que pode ser ou não um tópico de ML dependendo da ementa de alguns cursos de IA] para treinar um algoritmo que consiga resolver sozinho um XOR, neste exemplo são usados 2 entradas, 3 camadas ocultas e uma saída, quando clicamos em iniciar treinamento ele mostra quantas iterações foram necessárias para que o sistema aprendesse sozinho o comportamento do XOR.

Comment: As matérias são ensinadas em módulos diferentes porque existem muitas aplicações e conceitos distintos. Obrigado!

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1

Answer (score 8):

> Atenção: A abordagem deste post é apenas uma das formas de tratar um
>   assunto totalmente amplo como a inteligência artificial. Ele deve ser
>   entendimento como objetivamente e resumidamente didático e não deve ser interpretado
>   como verbete fechado, verdade absoluta ou fonte primária. O
>   StackOverflow em português é um site de perguntas e respostas
>   objetivas, e não faz parte de seu escopo a elaboração de temas
>   extensos. Para questões mais elucidativas, tratar no chat ou
>   documentação específica do assunto!

*Inteligência artificial* é uma área multidisciplinar envolvendo psicologia,filosofia, computação, matemática, e como lembrado pela contribuição do membro Luiz Vieira, aprendidas também em outros cursos como o curso de economia.

*Aprendizado de máquina* é uma das matérias aprendidas dentro da disciplina *inteligência artificial*, que trata de abordagens de algoritmos de aprendizado computacional. Aprendizado é um dos comportamentos conhecidos do fenômeno da inteligência.

Acompanhe o seguinte raciocínio:

> - 1 - Homens São feitos de átomos.
> - 2 - Mulheres são feitas de átomos.
> - Conclusão - Homens e mulheres são do mesmo gênero sexual, pois são feitos de átomos.

Essa é uma pequena demonstração de falácia de composição, que pode induzir a raciocínios errados. Esse exemplo não se trata de dizer que o assunto do tópico se trata disso, ou que abordagens diferentes apontem para isso, mas uma advertência para que assuntos tão co-relacionados não caiam em falácia. Portanto, do ponto de vista conceitual semântico, Inteligência Artificial e Aprendizado de Máquina são conceitos diferente. O que não quer dizer que, dependendo da abordagem, em algum momento, possam significar a mesma atividade. Tudo depende de como é contextualizado. Espero ter contribuído e não ter dado a impressão de ser um assunto fechado.

Por fim, recomento o livro "[Inteligência Artificial](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8535237011)" de Peter Norvig e Stuart Russell. No Brasil é distribuido pela editora Campus. Pode encontrar pela Amazon.

É possível encontrar também esse livro em boas livrarias de renome.

Comment: Olá Paulo. Muitas das técnicas de AM são aprendidas *também* em outros cursos (principalmente de estatística e economia): [regressão linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_linear), [inferência bayesiana](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infer%C3%AAncia_bayesiana), etc. Por isso, embora a sua resposta esteja certa, ela não é necessariamente canônica. Acho que vale editar para adicionar essa observação. Outra coisa é: a recomendação do livro está ok, mas a frase final pareceu propaganda. Eu removeria essa frase para evitar que a sua resposta seja caracterizada como SPAM.

Comment: Editei a parte final. 
Mas queria uma sugestão de como editar a parte inicial para o autor da pergunta, e quem tiver a mesma dúvida, compreender que estes resumos não são verdades absolutas. Você tem privilégios de edição, poderia melhorar isso para mim? Se não for abuso da minha parte.

Comment: Você também pode editar amigo.

Comment: Eu sei, mas queria uma sugestão!
Achou que vou deixar simplesmente uma observação.

Comment: Vc diz editar na pergunta do AP? Acho que não precisa. Você pode colocar qualquer sugestão diretamente na sua resposta. Acho que faz parte da resposta mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

a visão de que ML é uma subcategoria de IA está correta, porém para ficar mais claro esse entendimento, é importante que você saiba que quando falamos de IA, estamos falando de um enorme variedade de matérias, algumas delas são:sistemas especialistas, aprendizagem de máquina, algoritmos de busca, etc.

Em geral as disciplinas de IA, se preocupam em apresentar uma visão geral dessas matérias, promovendo um entendimento do que existe e das possibilidades possíveis, e diante disso o aluno/pesquisador/engenheiro/programador poderá escolher qual a subcategoria vai investigar melhor. Isto pode ser feito através de disciplinas mais específicas, como a de aprendizagem de máquina, que busca  trazer um conhecimento mais profundo de técnicas, como: Aprendizado baseado em árvores de decisão,  Rede neural artificial, Algoritmos genéticos, Clustering.

Comment: Não sei quem negativou seu post, porque está correto. Achei uma boa abordagem. Tem o meu +1. Até complementa minha resposta!

Comment: Opa @PauloSérgioDuff, eu também não entendi, mas kkkkkk e você tem razão, o seu foi bem mais elaborado e de certa forma todos que comentaram foram complementado a resposta um do outro. Valeu pelo +1. :D

Comment: Eu ainda vou comentar lá no Meta sobre DownVoters! A boa notícia é que quem tiver a mesma dúvida e procurar no google, vai ter informações ricas e detalhadas.

Answer (score 3):

**"Então por qual motivo ele é um curso totalmente distinto?"**

Essa pergunta independe de como realmente a máquina trabalha.

**"Teria a ver pelo motivo de serem assuntos muito complexos ou fazerem mais ou menos uso de algorítimos matemáticos?"**

Não existe computação sem algorítimos que utilizam de matemática... A quantidade ou o tamanho está relacionado com o algorítimo em si, depende do que ele vai fazer, mas tanto AI que irá definir toda uma gama de comportamentos e interpretações quanto o ML que irá absorver essa definições, vão utilizar uma quantidade razoável de complexidade.

Não tenho dúvida que são termos intimamente relacionados e que ML é uma sub-categoria de AI.

A diferença ao meu ver, já que afirmo que ML é sub-categoria de AI, é que AI está mais ligada a funções cognitivas inerentes ao ser humano, e que ML se utiliza desses conceitos para aprender e executar.

Ao meu ver é como se AI fosse a teoria e ML a prática.

**Então respondendo a sua pergunta, "Por que Inteligência Artificial e Aprendizagem de Máquina são matérias diferentes?"** ...

Não são matérias diferentes, são matérias complementares...

[Aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizado_de_m%C3%A1quina) você pode ver que ML é sub-categoria de AI, claro que é wiki, mas pela lógica podemos concordar que sim...

> > A aprendizagem automática ou aprendizado de máquina (em inglês: "machine learning") é um sub-campo da ciência da computação que evoluiu do estudo de reconhecimento de padrões e da teoria da aprendizagem computacional em inteligência artificial.

E [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computadores_e_intelig%C3%AAncia#Aprendizado_de_M.C3.A1quina) pode ver o um pouco mais pela mente de um dos precursores da AI.

Comment: Grande @MagicHat, apenas observar que eu disse "fazerem mais ou menos uso" e não "que não utilizem". Eu disse isso por que ao ver os requisitos desse dois cursos, um pedia uma nível mais avançado que outro.

Comment: Ah sim. relendo pude entender melhor, mas a quantidade de algorítimo está ligada ao algorítimo em si, ambos vão usar uma quantidade considerável. Pelas respostas sobre AI e ML indicadas no comentário de sua pergunta, poderás ver que não é algo curto;

Comment: "Não tenho dúvida que são termos intimamente relacionados e que ML é uma sub-categoria de AI." Eu concordo, e até acho que a maioria das pessoas concorde. Mas [há quem discorde](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-differences-between-artificial-intelligence-and-machine-learning): "*[...] Following this line of reasoning, Machine Learning is NOT a subset of AI. It really is the ONLY kind of AI there is.*"; e também "*Machine learning doesn't care about intelligent behaviour but accuracy and patterns.*".

Comment: @LuizVieira Entendo, refutar não só é valido como necessário,  entretanto acredito que usando da lógica minha afirmação se torna irrefutável, não creio haver ML sem o entendimento da AI, e creio que AI é um termo anterior...https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Machine_Learning_Research ,  mas posso estar errado...

Comment: Cara, como eu disse, eu não discordo. Mas é que isso depende muito da interpretação do indivíduo, principalmente sob a luz do problema que ele tá tratando. [Essa imagem](http://www.enterrasolutions.com/media/data-mining-Venn-diagram.png) (que é mencionada lá no link que eu referi) ilustra essa sua "lógica irrefutável". Só que ao mesmo tempo ela ilustra como isso tudo é tão multidisciplinar que eu me pergunto se ficar discutindo isso não é discutir o sexo dos anjos. Talvez seja mais útil discutir se determinada técnica pertence à área X ou Y (e ainda assim eu tenho as minhas dúvidas rs).

Comment: @LuizVieira não disse que vc discordava, só disse que o link que enviou de certa forma refutando a ideia é que é refutável(e foi refutado com essa imagem que se refere). Não acho que dependa de interpretação, e como eu disse não vejo como separar ML de AI, mas vejo AI sem ML... hehe mas entendo sua preocupação no que tange a utilidade, mas ai a pergunta seria outra,,, nussa parece que aprendi essa palavra hj (refutar)...kkkk.. Tem horas que a formalidade, me faz parecer mei bobo... Bom dia man....